# What are all of the characters that will break an <img> tag if used in its filename

Tags: html

The characters I have come across that will break an image in a HTML page if used in the image’s filename are:

```
& / \ *
```

Are there any other filename characters that would cause an image to not display?

The reason I’m asking is I need to store an image of some text and need to replace invalid characters in the filename.

This mechanism is in place, just trying to find a quick list of characters to save the tester some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, this is little to do with HTML and a lot to do with the OS your sever is running on.

It looks like Windows here, so the characters for that are

```
\ / : * ? < > |
```

The `&` however, is likely a property of HTML.  You can probably still use them in your files, but for the HTML, put `&amp;` instead of `&`.  If you don't want to do this, you can always disallow `&`s in the files as well.

Comment: The &'s in the filename definitely break the <img> tag (at least in this case it does).

It is Windows.

It's obvious why most of those characters would break a URL regardless of the server etc.

Thanks for the list.

Comment: @Dan - What programming language are you using server-side?  PHP?  C#?  ColdFusion?